# Java HttpSession not working in web server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, httpsession

I have a problem with HttpSessions when I use them in web server. 
Project based on Spring MVC and works fine locally, but when I endure it on real web server session not working. I use them for user logging. Code of user login:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/system/login.do","/system/login.do/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam("username") String login, @RequestParam("password") String passwd, 
        HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            UserModel user = new UserModel().getUser(login, passwd); 
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("user",  user);
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + "/system/panel");

}
```

In web server I use Apache and Tomcat 8. 
Also in web.xml sessions is enabled.
I would appreciate any help.

This is how I check session in admin JSP-page:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.user == null}">
    <c:redirect url="/index"/>
</c:if>
```

And the example of use info in session:

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.user.username}"/>
```

Comment: What do you see? What have you tried? Have you added Logging to find out where it goes wrong?

Comment: I figured that the problem is in the session recording . Redirection is to a page where is checking session, and because it is not available, page redirect to index. I also check session when it is recording and I received empty result. Logging is also empty

Comment: maybe you can provide with the code the checks the existence of the session. It seems that this part of the code is right, but we need more info.

Comment: added more code examples

Comment: Are you accepting cookies on your browser?

Comment: Yes, sure i accepting